# Error when connecting to the nem test node with node.js

Tags: node.js, npm, nem

After typing the commands in the terminal (mac): `npm init` and `npm install nem-sdk`

I create a main.js script in the same file:

```
let nem = require("nem-sdk").default;
let endpoint = nem.model.objects.create("endpoint") 
(nem.model.nodes.defaultTesnet, nem.model.nodes.defaultPort);
nem.com.requests.chain.lastBlock(endpoint).then(function(block) { 
    console.log(block);
    }, function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

when I launched this file I got the following error msg:

[image: error]

Comment: looks like you have to specify an endpoint to a valid node like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nem-sdk#41---create-endpoints

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you misspelled testnet in `nem.model.nodes.defaultTesnet`. It should be `nem.model.nodes.defaultTestnet`